# Use c++ dll typedif in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, typedef

I have c++ dll project and at this, I have a typedef declaration like this

```
typedef void* ScreenNode;
```

and in my header file i use this deceleration

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int CB_AddProgramColor (ScreenNode g_screen_node,ProgramNode program_node,int color, int alpha);
```

Now, I wand to use this function in C# with a class like this

```
internal unsafe partial class BBIA
{
[DllImport(dllName)]
        public static extern
            int CB_initNode(ScreenNode g_screen_node, int width, int heigth,EN_DevType EN_C1Dev);
}
```

but I take error on **ScreenNode** ***g_screen_node*** with this detail.

"**Error    1   The type or namespace name 'ScreenNode' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**"

I have 2 question:

1. I have to declare **typedef void* ScreenNode** in C# Project?
2. My typedef is in void data type. what can i do for this declaration in C#?

Comment: The closest thing in C# to typedef is the aliased 'using' applied to types: e.g., "using Foo = System.Datetime;", which would allow you to specify 'Foo' instead of 'Datetime' in that file (doesn't help for your example however).  Like the 'typedef' in C++, this doesn't always enhance code clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# does not have `typedef`, so you have to specify type (not alias) in all places where you use it. For C++ `void*` you can use `void*` or `IntPtr` in C#.

Comment: See my comment above - C# does have an aliased 'using' syntax which allows you to use a different name for a type, however it won't allow this with void*.